# Rails - View Template - Insert <BR> within ERB Tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to insert HTML `<BR>` tag within the link_to ERB tag as show below:

```
<%= link_to((@Name + "<BR>" + @Surname), my_action_path %>
```

What would be the correct way of doing this?

Comment: `link_to` also takes a block which means you have more latitude in how you format things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= link_to( raw(@Name+"<br>"+@Surname) , my_action_path ) %>
```

You can achieve this using 'raw' function provided by rails.

Comment: You only need to use `raw` if the string might be nil. In this case, we know the input, so `html_safe` is fine. I'm not saying `raw` is wrong -- it still works -- just pointing out the basic difference between the two methods.

Answer (score 2):

```
(@Name + "<BR>" + @Surname).html_safe
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `@Name` and `@Surname` seem like they could be user-entered, you'll want to be careful here...

```
<% @name = "<script>alert('bad');</script>First Name"
   @surname = "<script>alert('another bad');</script>Last Name" %>

<%= link_to(("".html_safe + @name + "<br />".html_safe + @surname), '#') %>
```

Trying with either of the other answers leaves you with 2 alert boxes (meaning you now have a [XSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) vulnerability)...this way outputs the script tags as text